# Issue with Plotly

Tags: plotly

I used the following code to do plot a figure in python, but it does return anything at all. Does anyboday know why this happend? And how can I fix it?  Thank you.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species")
fig.show()
```

Comment: what error does it throw?

Comment: It does return any error at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this in a Jupyter Notebook, then you need to install the extensions.

See the following from the repo's readme:

#### Jupyter Notebook Support

For use in the Jupyter Notebook, install the `notebook` and `ipywidgets`
packages using pip...

```
pip install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets==7.5"
```

or conda.

```
conda install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets=7.5"
```

#### JupyterLab Support (Python 3.5+)

For use in JupyterLab, install the `jupyterlab` and `ipywidgets`
packages using pip...

```
pip install jupyterlab "ipywidgets==7.5"
```

or conda.

```
conda install jupyterlab "ipywidgets=7.5"
```

Then run the following commands to install the required JupyterLab extensions (note that this will require [`node`](https://nodejs.org/) to be installed):

```
# Basic JupyterLab renderer support
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.9.0

# OPTIONAL: Jupyter widgets extension for FigureWidget support
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager plotlywidget@4.9.0
```

Please check out our [Troubleshooting guide](https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/) if you run into any problems with JupyterLab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works well. I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: happy to help, Amy - remember that you can accept an answer if you find it useful